# How to redirect Java request to a PHP page with POST parameters through htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a Java Swing program, where the user enters login data in a dialog, then submits it. The data is then sent (using POST) to a validation script page in my website to validate it.

My old website validation script page was "**validate_data.php**" and the data was sent to it fine to be validated, then i return a success message to the Java program. The problem is that i have now renewed my website to WordPress. The new validation page is "**validate-data**". So i have tried to redirect the Java program request through the htaccess file using the 5th line below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule validate_data\.php(\?.*) validate-data$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

#Redirect permanent /validate_data.php /validate-data
```

But when my Java program tries to connect to it, it throws a "FileNotFound" Exception. To test it i have tried using the Redirect commented line in the htaccess file mentioned above, and i found that the page was redirected fine to the new page, but with no parameters.

**Is there a reason why my RewriteRule is not working as expected?**

Comment: You will need to use WP's `rewrite` API as WP doesn't support internal rewrites.

Comment: @anubhava .. Thanks. I am checking this now. It's confusing though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone asking the same question, i was able to fix this using WordPress's rewrite API as "anubhava" has advised me, thanks to him, and i have posted how i did it here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/243676/wordpress-rewrite-does-not-work-for-some-reason